# Get record from three tables sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the three tables, I want the `table3` details with `table_1.field_id`. Now am getting the full record without the `table_1.field_id`. How can I include the `table1.field_id` with `table_3` records?

Query:

```
select 
   fld_id, fld_name, fld_date 
from 
   table_3
where 
   fld_item_id in (select fld_id 
                   from tbl_table2 
                   where fld_cust_id in (select fld_id 
                                         from table_1 
                                         where fld_ref_id = 100));
```

**Table3**:

```
FLD_ID FLD_Name FLD_DATE     FLD_ITEM_ID
101       hai   12-01-2013   10
```

**Table 2**:

```
FLD_ID FLD_value FLD_CUST_ID  FLD_DATE     
10       100     10000        12-01-2013
```

**Table 1**:

```
FLD_ID FLD_NAME fld_ref_id  FLD_DATE
10000  Vinoth   100         12-01-2013
```

Comment: show your table schema please

Comment: use `join` to get all the relevant data

Answer (score 2):

Try (as sugested by RBarryYoung)

```
SELECT B.fld_cust_id Table1FieldId, C.fld_id, C.fld_name, C.fld_date 
FROM tbl_table2 B
INNER JOIN table_3 C ON C.fld_item_id = B.fld_id
WHERE A.fld_ref_id=100
```

or (If you need other fields from `table_1` )

```
SELECT A.fld_id Table1FieldId, C.fld_id, C.fld_name, C.fld_date 
FROM table_1 A
INNER JOIN tbl_table2 B ON B.fld_cust_id = A.fld_id 
INNER JOIN table_3 C ON C.fld_item_id = B.fld_id
WHERE A.fld_ref_id=100
```

Comment: If all you want is the Table_1.FLD_ID, you don't actually need to join to it since it's the same as the Table_2.FLD_CUST_ID.